# Servicestack Session is null only when using JWT

Tags: jwt, servicestack

This fails on SessionAs in the baseservice in Postman when I authenticate via JWT. But when I use Basic Auth it works fine. Anyone know why?

Apphost

```
    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
        new IAuthProvider[]
        {
            new BasicAuthProvider(),                    //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
            new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
                AuthKeyBase64 = AppSettings.GetString("jwt.auth.key"),
                RequireSecureConnection = false,
                }, //JWT TOKENS
            new CredentialsAuthProvider(AppSettings)
        })
    {
```

BaseService
    public class ServiceBase: Service
        {

```
        public IUserAuth UserAuth
        {
            get
            {
                var session = SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
                return AuthRepository.GetUserAuth(session.UserAuthId);   
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SessionAs<T>` needs to match the UserSession Type registered in the `AuthFeature` plugin which is `CustomUserSession`.

[ServiceStack's JwtAuthProvider](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) populates the `UserAuthId` in the JWT's `sub` JWT Payload so you should check the Raw HTTP Headers to make sure the JWT Token is being sent, either in HTTP's `Authorization` Header as a BearerToken or in the `ss-tok` Cookie. If it is being sent you decode the JWT sent in https://jwt.io to make sure it contains a valid payload, in this case it contains a `"sub"` property in the JWT payload containing the `UserAuthId` of the user being authenticated.